# Difference of parity PoA between Validator Sets and Aura?

Tags: parity, poa

It seems there are two PoA consensus algorithms in parity PoA.  What is the difference between [Validator Sets](https://wiki.parity.io/Validator-Set.html) and [Aura](https://wiki.parity.io/Aura.html)?

Comment: Misconception here: aura is the only PoA consensus algorithm in parity currently, and the validator set is part of the configuration of any PoA network, example here: https://wiki.parity.io/Pluggable-Consensus.html#aura

Comment: Maybe not Validator Sets, but Validator engines. It seems there are Ethash, Instant Seal, Validator engines and Aura in that page.

Comment: Aura uses Validator Set.